# How to convert this XML into HTML?

Tags: html, xml

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Diary>
<Event EventName="J.Edgar" Classification="2011 Movies" EventStart="2012-03-19T07:00:00+00:00" EventEnd="2012-03-19T08:00:00+00:00" />
<Event EventName="Titanic" Classification="1997 Movies" EventStart="2012-03-19T09:00:00+00:00" EventEnd="2012-03-19T10:00:00+00:00" />
....
</Diary>
```

How can I create an automatic table (with HTML and CSS)? these details of EventName, etc.. are automatic and I need something Dynamic for it.

I tried using W3 tutorials but didn't manage to get anything out of it. This XML file looks different than regular ones as well.

Please let me know if you have an idea.
Many thanks!

Comment: Learn XSLT, write a script, come back here when you hit a specific problem.

Comment: I was trying to get this like this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Best Movies</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Movie</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Diary/Event">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="EventName"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Classification"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet> Not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StyleSheets http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/WhatIsXSL.html. There should be utilities in each programming language to transform XML with XSL.

Comment: I would like to get something more specific for my example if it's possible. I've read the page that you have sent me but didn't get to a solution out of it.

Comment: I was trying to get this like this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Best Movies</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Movie</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Diary/Event">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="EventName"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Classification"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet> Not working...

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="EventName"/>  EventName is no element its an attribute of the element Event. Within the for-each you can refer the Event element with a dot .